# In AS3 calling loadBytes 2 times in sequence wont work

Tags: actionscript-3, loader

While my code is pretty big and fragmented over many files to show here, i basically boils down to this:

I have a function which does this:

```
var loadedScript:Loader;
function load():void{
    loadedScript = new Loader();
    // loadedScript is initilized somewhere and other stuff
    loadedScript.loadBytes(bytes, context);
    loadedScript.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, scriptLoaded, false, 0, true);
}
```

when i call this function 2 times in a row in such a way that its called the 2. time before loadedScript.loadBytes(bytes, context); from the 1. time can finish, then the "scriptLoaded" method is called only for the 2. time, not the 1. time

So, is this intentional behaivor from the loadedScript.loadBytes(bytes, context); method, or a bug, cann i bypass this somehow?

Comment: you better create a `loadedScript` for each thing you want to load. If you re-assign something to it, the first one gets overwritten

Comment: @Marijn i edited the question, could u please take a look again?

Comment: I think Marion's comments still apply. According to the code you've shown, you blow away the first Loader, when you call the function the second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could ofcourse create a loader-queue, something like this:

```
var queue:Array = new Array();
function load(bytesToLoad:*):void {
    queue.push(bytesToLoad);
    processQueue();
}

function processQueue():void {
    //check if items are on queue
    if (queue.length > 0) {
        //create a loader
        var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
        //add event for loading complete
        ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, scriptLoaded, false, 0, true);
        //load the bytes (get first item from the queue, which contains the bytes to load)
        ldr.loadBytes(queue.shift(), context);
    }
}

function scriptLoaded():void {
     //do stuff

     //process next item in queue
     processQueue();
}
```

Comment: I implemented your idea (with a few changes) and it works great if i put break points everywhere, it really does what it should, but as soon as i skip all break point, it refuses to go into the handler method `scriptLoaded()`.

Comment: Well, i am making some kind of GUI designer, in which you can write event methods to you components which works fine, but when i give 2 components a creationComplete event, then the second event starts before `loadedScript.loadBytes()` can finish the first one, so the first one gets canceled, so after implementing your answer, in the mothod `load()` it does `queue.push(bytesToLoad)` every time, but `processQueue();` only when there is no loading going on, all of which works fine whit breakpoint, but without them it dosnt go into `scriptLoaded` even once

Comment: Probably because the bytes are already loaded, it will go sync, instead of async. Try replacing the Event.COMPLETE with Event.INIT

Comment: i used the `setTimeout` to do `ldr.loadBytes()` and it works now, thanks for the help